# Setting inline backgroundImage is not working in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, inline-styles

I am using a function which will return the full path of the image.

```
  const imagePath = (imagePath) => {
    const domainPath = "http://localhost:9005/gallery/original/";
    const fullImagePath = domainPath + imagePath;
    return fullImagePath;
  };
```

Now If I use below code, it will work and show image on browser:

```
<img
 src={imagePath(item.mediaPath)}
 alt="cow images"
/>
```

But If I use below code, it will NOT work:

```
<div
  className="bg-image-blur"
  style={{
    backgroundImage:
      "url(" +
      imagePath(item.mediaPath) +
      ")",
  }}
></div>
```

Please see given below image from my inspect element. Style is added to the element :
[image]

and It will also not work if I don't use `imagePath` function :

```
<div
  className="bg-image-blur"
  style={{
    backgroundImage:
      "url(" +
      "http://localhost:9005/gallery/original/" +
      id.mediaPath +
      ")",
  }}
></div>
```

What is the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you haven't put `''` for `url`. And I'd suggest you use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for your string concat instead for easier look

```
<div
  className="bg-image-blur"
  style={{
    backgroundImage: `url('${imagePath(item.mediaPath)}')`,
  }}
></div>
```

You can check [this document](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) to understand how `background-image` looks like with `url`

Comment: Yes, I am already using template string. I just wrote an example here without template string